# На устройствах Apple не корректно отображается кнопка отправки формы

Tags: css, apple

У нас на сайте описана в CSS внешний вид кнопки, но на устройствах Apple эта кнопка отображается не корректно, заменяется на стандартную кнопку Apple.

Как это исправить? Пробовала прописать вендорные префиксы, но результата это не дало.

Comment: весь необходимый код: html,css должен быть в вопросе. Без знания того, какие стили используются нельзя сказать какие из них и почему не применяются

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте для **необходимых** элементов:

```
.box {-webkit-appearance: none;}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, это помогло!

Comment: @AllaAkbirova, тогда примите пожалуйста ответ как верный (зеленая галкка рядом с рейтингом ответа), и проголосуйте за него, чтобы автор получил заслуженную репутацию, потверждающую его экстрасенсорные способности

Comment: Ну и я не верстальщик, но -moz-appearance для верности бы тоже добавил

Comment: кстати да, экстрасенсорные способности довольно редки в наше время и заслуживают как минимум зеленой галки, а лучше две. -moz-appearance абсолютно бесполезен для IOS - увы и ах)))

Comment: @СергейВ. конечно поставлю, но моей репутации еще не хватает для того, чтобы голос имел вес. Спасибо за помощь )